# How to scroll a UICollectionView using a button?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell which contains an image and button. When I tap on the "next" button, it should scroll horizontally to the next image of the UICollectionView. Any idea on how to implement this using Swift?

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

here count is number of currently showed image.

```
count = count+1    
let index = IndexPath.init(item: counter, section: 0)
self.collectionview.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

note:- you must set width of cell equal to screen width